# Consulta MYSQL trazer resultados por ordem de distância usando coordenadas

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela que tem as coordenadas (latitude e longitude) dos usuarios.

Como faço fazer uma consulta para trazer quem está mais próximo da localização.

Ex:

```
ID |     Lat    | Long
1  | -22.874428 | -43.372334
2  | -20.292799 | -40.301991
```

Trazer esses dois onde o id 2 estaria mais próximo (coordenadas de busca: -20.292799 | -40.301991)

Gostaria que a consulta trouxesse algo do tipo

```
ID | Distancia
1  | 2km
2  | 20km
```

- o 2km e 20km seriam calculados dentro da consulta sql

Comment: Você tem os dados das coordenadas de referência? E você sabe calcular a distância utilizando coordenadas?

Comment: tenho os dados sim, esse por exemplo: -20.292799 | -40.301991. Não sei calcular a distância.. :/

Comment: Esse aí só traz a distância específica, preciso que traga a consulta uma coluna com a distância, para que possa fazer a ordenação, vou editar a pergunta para ficar melhor, obrigado.

Comment: Qual o valor da origem? Pois, como vai calcular a distancia se não sabe onde começa? Essa distancia seria em linha reta certo? E não utilizando um sistema de ruas para verificar a distancia, certo?

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue calcular a distancia usando uma expressão aritmética, exemplo:

```
SELECT
    l.id,
    l.lat,
    l.lng,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(c.lat) ) 
              * cos( radians( l.lat ) ) 
              * cos( radians( l.lng ) - radians(c.lng) ) 
              + sin( radians(c.lat) ) 
              * sin( radians( l.lat ) ) ) ) AS distancia 
FROM
    locais AS l
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        -20.282957 AS lat,
        -40.401991 AS lng
    ) AS c
ORDER BY
    distancia
```

Fiddle rodando o exemplo acima: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pFEVDYaXQyj81g2kh6VLBw/2